# Faster way to group data in the same quartile range

Tags: matlab, statistics

Consider a column of a 10 x 10 matrix K, say K(:,1)

I would like to create a 10x4 binary matrix which tells us which quarter range the row entry belongs to. For example

```
   ith row of binary matirx : [ 1 0 0 0 ] => K(i,1)<prctile(K(:,1),25)
```

My code:

```
   %%%

   K = randi(10,10);
   BINMAT = zeros(size(K,1),4);

   y_1 = prctile(K(:,1),25) ; 
   ID_1 = find(K(:,1) < y_1);
   BINMAT(ID_1,1)=1;

   y_2 = prctile(K(:,1),50);
   ID_2 = find(( K(:,1) > y_1 &  K(:,1) < y_2 ));
   BINMAT(ID_2,2)=1;

   y_3 = prctile(K(:,1),75);
   ID_3 = find(( K(:,1) > y_2 & K(:,1) < y_3 ));
   BINMAT(ID_3,3)=1;

   y_4 = prctile(K(:,1),100);
   ID_4 = find((K(:,1) > y_3 & K(:,1) < y_4 ));
   BINMAT(ID_4,4)=1;
   %%%
```

If I have to do this not just for one column but for a set of columns, say A = [ 1 2 5 6], and BINMAT should have 16 columns (4 for each column of K) .Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop that iterates over the desired column indexes given by `A`:

```
K = randi(10,10);
A = [1 2 5 6]; % columns in K to process
BINMAT = zeros(size(K,1), 4*length(A));

cnt = 0; % helper
for col_indx = A
    y_1 = prctile(K(:,col_indx),25) ;
    ID_1 = find(K(:,col_indx) < y_1);
    BINMAT(ID_1, 4*cnt + 1) = 1;

    y_2 = prctile(K(:,col_indx),50);
    ID_2 = find(( K(:,col_indx) > y_1 &  K(:,col_indx) < y_2 ));
    BINMAT(ID_2, 4*cnt + 2)=1;

    y_3 = prctile(K(:,col_indx),75);
    ID_3 = find(( K(:,col_indx) > y_2 & K(:,col_indx) < y_3 ));
    BINMAT(ID_3, 4*cnt + 3)=1;

    y_4 = prctile(K(:,col_indx),100);
    ID_4 = find((K(:,col_indx) > y_3 & K(:,col_indx) < y_4 ));
    BINMAT(ID_4, 4*cnt + 4)=1;

    cnt = cnt + 1;
end
```

I have noticed that many of the rows of `BINMAT` contain only zeros because the code you posted does not take values equal to `y_1`, `y_2`, `y_3` and `y_4` into account. I think you should use `K(:,col_indx) >= y_1 ...` and so on.

Comment: Thanks Deve! But, yeah I tried looping it myself but its too slow if I have a larger K. 

I was wondering if there might be way to vectorize the process of getting the ID's.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I guess you could throw together some matrix containing all the criteria for `find` but I doubt that it'll speed up the whole thing significantly.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion:

```
K = randi(10,10)
p = 25:25:100;
Y = prctile(K, p);
Y = [zeros(1, size(Y, 2)) ;Y];
BINMAT = zeros(size(K, 1), length(p), size(K, 2));

for j = 1:size(K, 2)
    for i = 1:length(p)
    BINMAT(Y(i, j) <= K(:,j) & K(:, j) <= Y(i+1, j), i, j) = 1;
    end
end
```

Then, `BINMAT(:, :, i)` is the binary matrix, as you defined it, for `K(:, i)`.

Answer (score 0):

Percentile is, at its heart, the position of an element in the sorted list.  So using `sort` directly will provide the most efficient solution, since you want multiple percentiles out of multiple columns.

First we need a way to assign fixed bins to the sorted positions.  Here's the vector that I think prctile uses, but since 10 doesn't split evenly into 4 bins, it's somewhat arbitrary.  (in other words, do you assign element 3 to the 0-25% bin or the 25%-50% bin)?  `floor(4*(0.5+(0:9).')/10)+1`

Now we just need to sort each column, and assign the sort position of each original element to one of those positions.  The second output of sort does most of the work:

```
K = randi(10,10);
A = [1 2 5 6]; % columns in K to process
BINMAT = zeros(size(K,1), 4*length(A));
bins = floor(4*(0.5+(0:9).')/10)+1;

[sortedK, idx] = sort(K(:,A));

% The k'th element of idx belongs to the c(k) bin.  So now generate the output.
% We need to offset to the correct block of BINMAT for each column
offset_bins = bsxfun(@plus, bins, 4*(0:length(A)-1));
BINMAT(sub2ind(size(BINMAT), idx, offset_bins)) = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Peter! I agree with your logic. However, the code seems to be spitting out some errors when I run it. 
Error using sub2ind (line 47)
The subscript vectors must all be of the same size.

Error in otherCode_QD (line 10)
BINMAT(sub2ind(size(BINMAT), idx, offset_bins)) = 1;

Comment: Could it be a copy/paste error?  I can paste this into a clean MATLAB session with no problem.  Or have you tried to modify it for different sized vectors, and missed a modification?